# Count() function updates after page refresh php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have made a simple cart in which i have a div which will be showed on hover which possess purchased items. The problem is each time i click on `add to cart` button. It does not count the cart items at instance. All i need to do is to refresh my page by myself. Any suggestions or help will be appreciable.

**Code**

```
  <div id="cartContainer">
  <div id="cart">
  <li style="color: #515151">
  <img id="cart_img" src="images/cart.png">
  Cart <span class='badge' id='comparison-count'>
  <?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])&& !empty($_SESSION['cart'])&& count($_SESSION['cart'])>0)
   {
   echo count($_SESSION['cart']);
    }
  else {
  $cart_count=0;
  echo $cart_count;
  }
 ?>
  </span>
 </li>
  <div id="sidebar">
   <?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])&& !empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
  ?>
   <table id="s_table">
   <?php
   foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value){
     //here it shows the item details
     }
    ?>
   </table>
   </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Add a no-cache header?

Comment: @developerwjk how it will help me?

Comment: Server script will not run on hover on the front end.

Comment: How is Add To Cart implemented?  Perhaps you can account for the count change there.

Comment: I assume after a form submit to add to cart you redirect back to a page that shows the cart and the problem is at first it doesn't show the new item, then you refresh and it does. If that's the issue, its a cache issue.

Comment: @developerwjk you have assumed correct!! but can you please help me how can i set it. It's a new thing to me!!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are doing `add-to-cart` by `ajax` call.

Now on your ajax success do this

```
var no_of_item = Number($("#comparison-count").html());
var new_no_of_item = no_of_item + no_of_item_purchased_in_last_add_to_cart;
$("#comparison-count").html(new_no_of_item);
```

If you are not doing it by ajax,then add the product to cart at the beginning of the php file before echoing any html tag.

Comment: how can i get this `no_of_item_purchased_in_last_add_to_cart`

Comment: @tabia There should be an input field to enter the no of item to purchase , else it will be 1.